# Posicion del cursor SearchView Android

Tags: android-studio, cursor, searchview

Estoy buscando la manera de posicionar el cursor de un SearchView al inicio del texto. Lo que hago es que rescato un texto y lo coloco en el SearchView y el cursor queda posicionado al final de éste.

Se que en EditText existe el setSelection(), pero no encuentro un método similar en SearchView.

¿Habrá alguna manera de hacerlo?

Espero su respuesta, Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

el SearchView contiene un EditText dentro al que le deberias poder mover el cursor con el setSelection(). para poder acceder al EditText podes hacer algo asi:

```
EditText searchText = (EditText) searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);
```

Comment: Gracias amigo, probaré y te comento el resultado.

Comment: Funciona perfectamente @ErickSilva